# My CentOS do not have the brief command vie0

Tags: centos, interface

I watch a video, theres has a brief command:
[image: open]

I use `vie0`, but there do not have this command:

```
[root@ansible-master ~]# vie0
-bash: vie0: command not found
```

---

My CentOS version is: CentOS 7.2

Answer (score 0):

the bashrc do the trick.

```
vi /etc/bashrc
alias vie0='vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0'
source /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: Probably better to add a file to /etc/profile.d/ than adding it to bashrc.